# How to use Contains-filter to expanded table using Odata

Tags: c#, expression, odata

I am not able to use Contains-filter to expanded table:

```
 var customersData = await myClient.For<Customer>()
            .Filter(t => t.name.Contains(searchCriteria) || t.PersonTable.ContactNumber.Contains(searchCriteria))
            .Expand(t => new { t.PersonTable, t.AddressesTable })
            .FindEntriesAsync();
```

I tried using new version 4.12 like below also:

```
var filter = new ODataExpression<Customer>(t => t.name.Contains(searchCriteria));
        filter = filter || new ODataExpression<PersonTable>(x => x.ContactNumber.Contains(searchCriteria));
        var result3 = await myClient.For<Customer>().Filter(filter).FindEntriesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter generic type is different from the type you use in For clause, i.e. you query on Customer table and send a filter on PersonTable. The library should probably detect this and throw an exception. Anyway this won't work.